# como crear un procedimiento almacenado que inserte datos de una tabla diferente

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

hola estoy intendo hacer que la tabla anterior que tengo inserte los datos nuevos en la nueva tabla pero en un procedimiento almacenado y que los campos fecheEsperada y fechaEntrega se inserten como nulos en la nueva tabla pero no me inserta nada

```
delimiter $$
create procedure TRANS_5 (in codigoPedido1 int)
begin
declare tum int;
start transaction;
CREATE TABLE Trans_Pedidos LIKE Pedidos;
INSERT INTO Trans_Pedidos SELECT * FROM Pedidos where CodigoPedido=codigoPedido1 ;
set tum=(select fecheEsperada,fechaEntrega where CodigoPedido=codigoPedido1 );
if tum is null then 
rollback;
else
commit;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

me aparece que esta bien el procedimiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero al momento de verificar si se registro a la nueva tabla no hay nada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la tabla `Trans_Pedidos` es temporal deberías eliminarla una vez que se hagan los inserts. Si ejecutas solo el `insert` funciona?

Comment: ni con el insert me funciona no me esta insertando los datos de la tabla anterior

Comment: no cuando ejecuto el procedimiento me dice que ya se creo pero al momento de verificar si se inserto a la nueva tabla no me aparece nada

Comment: Pero si estás ejecutando el procedimiento almacenado? Una cosa es crear que es lo que no tienes errores y otra es ejecutarlo.

Comment: ya vi si me esta insertando me estaba faltando llamar el call solo me falta que al momento de insertar la fechaesperada yfecha de entrega sea nula

Comment: En el insert debes especificar las columnas y `null` en los que necesites.

Comment: si ya me salio gracias

Comment: No llego a entender qué problema quieres resolver con esto ¿? ¿Por qué debe crearse esa tabla cada vez? Quizá lo que estás necesitando es un `TRIGGER`